# Pair the Dell Mouse with the same Bluetooth dongle as the Keyboard's

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, dell

I was using a Keyboard and Mouse from Dell, bought together, that worked on the same usb dongle. However, my Mouse just broken and I bought a new one (also from Dell).

I want to pair this new mouse with my old usb dongle (or my keyboard with the new one). I've seen Dell provides the [Dell Peripheral Manager](https://www.dell.com/en-us/lp/dpem), which deals with these kind of situations, but they only provide Windows and Mac OS versions. I tried installing it via Lutris but it doesn't open, even though it installs fine.

Does anyone know how can I do it via Ubuntu (I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed). It is just horrible to have my two USB entries with two different USB Dongles from the same manufacturer.